# Revert Laravel app.name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I wanted to change the `app.name` of my Laravel project, the new name had a space in it. Since the change of the name I get the PHP error:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class App\Console\Kernel does not exist in D:\xampp\htdocs\sistemas\selecao-geral\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\ Container.php:752

I now wish to revert the name back but this fails due too the above stated error.

How can I change back the app name, could I maybe do this manually?

Comment: The error I'm getting:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class App\Console\Kernel does not exist in D:\xampp\htdocs\sistemas\selecao-geral\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\
Container.php:752

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Put the name in "quotes":**

```
APP_NAME="Your App's Name"
```

**And run:**

```
php artisan config:clear
```

to clear the config cache.

Comment: Also, run `php artisan config:clear` to clear the config cache.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Indeed. Thanks :)

Comment: I get the same error that I get when tried to serve. I forget to tell, but I've changed the app.name using: php artisan app:name "Selection System"

Comment: @PatrickPierre run `composer dump-autoload` and see if the error still persists

Comment: @PatrickPierre try changing the name manually in your `.env` file as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @SapneshNaik, I've tried, but doesn't work either... I had changed the APP_NAME, runned `php artisan config:clear` and get the same error (also with `composer dump-autoload` and `composer update`).

Comment: @SapneshNaik, Laravel 5.5

Comment: @PatrickPierre See the issue here https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6175

Comment: @PatrickPierre I think you need to revert your namespaces  back to `App` in your `composer.json` file

Comment: @SapneshNaik, I've done as you said and changed the namespaces on composer.json (I had to change the namespaces of some other files too, as their names were coming out with the error). After that I was able to run `php artisan config:clear` and `composer dump-autoload`. But now I'm facing another problem. I can serve the application and access the first page of my dashboard, but when I try to access any other route, it returns `Class Selection System\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController does not exist`. I think that there is some place I've not changed something, but can't figure out where...

Comment: @PatrickPierre As suggested in the link I mentioned have you checked things in `bootstrap\config.php`?

Comment: @SapneshNaik, I've just checked again, and it seems to be everything in order on `bootstrap\config.php`. I've updated the file before, but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @PatrickPierre I'm not entirely sure what might be the issue now. Please post it as another question, then even others will be able to help you :)

Comment: @PatrickPierre meanwhile if it helped you, Please accept the answer :)

Comment: So, after search for the whole yesterday's afternoon, I decided to go start all over and copy my controllers, views, routes, etc... I think it would be faster than continue trying to solve the problem, and everything is fine now, but thank you for the help, guys. \o

Comment: After running "APP_NAME="MyApp", I faced Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class MyApp\Http\Kernel does not exist. Then I couldn't run any "php artisan" comman i.e php artisan dump-autoload.
To solve this, I have to revert my changes by git and then I have to change "bootstrap/app.php" file manualy(as this was not added in my git). In this file I have to change the lines where my new app name("MyApp") is mentioned.

MyApp\Http\Kernel::class  should  changed to App\Http\Kernel::class.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 9):

Just ran into this problem today and I was able to fix it using these steps.
Take note that this problem occurred because I've accidentally set the application "namespace" using the artisan command

> php artisan app:name

instead of using the env variable APP_NAME to set the application name only

- Using your IDE(in my case I'm using SublimeText3) search for the app namespace you've set (in my case I've set my namespace to TestApp) for all files inside your project. Make sure you match the whole word to be sure.
- Replace the namespace to App (TestApp to App)
- Finally after saving all files with the replaced namespace run **composer dump-autoload**

Comment: I also changed all files with namespaces manually in the app directory and then I ran composer dump-autoload. This worked

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux(ubuntu), you can use **"sed"**
It changes all the occurrences of a string in the files that you give to another of your choice!

```
find /path/to/laravel/project -type f -exec \ sed -i 's/App\ Name\ With\ Space/NewNameWithNoSpaces/g' {} +
```

This means it finds all the files in the directory of your laravel project and apply the sed command on them

**PS:** do this on your own responsibility, other solutions are(start a new project, and learn from your mistake!), or manually change them which will never work!